# Crystal Reports error "A number, or currency amount is required here"

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, required

I am trying to format field according to this formula but get error "A number, or currency amount is required here":

`{pool_bearbeit.typ} in [1255,9100]`

Field type is smallint in SQL database. No idea what is wrong here...

Comment: SQL has IN (...), with regular parentheses.

Comment: I use Crystal Report here

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple. This maybe works for susped but not for format.
To format field I need to add colors this way:

```
if {pool_bearbeit.typ} in [1255,9100]
then crWhite
else crBlack
```

Nothing related with error message ...